# How to get the navigation bar fixed to the bottom instead of the top

Tags: html, css, navigation

The problem here is that my navigation bar is `fixed` to the top and I would like for it to be `fixed` to the bottom:

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<h1>My Resume</h1>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csstrial.css">
<center>

<div id="nav">
<p class="title"><a href="#">TheCodePress<span class="subtitle">.blogspot.com</span>              </a></p>
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">My Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="home.html" target='MYHOME'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="cmon.html" target='MYHOME'>Qualifications</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>


<iframe src="home.html" name="MYHOME" height="550" width="700"
frameborder="0">
```

And This is My CSS

```
#nav
 {
 background-color:#262626;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 50px #5E5E5E;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
}

.title
 {
 color:#EDEDED;
 font-family:verdana;
 font-size:25px;
 width:350px;
 margin-top:6px;
 margin-left:150px;
 font-weight:bold;
 float:left;
}
.subtitle 
{
 color:#EDEDED;
 font-family:verdana;
 font-size:15px;
}

#navigation
{
 list-style-type:none; 
}
li 
{
 display:inline;
 padding:10px;
}
#nav a
{
 font-family:verdana;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#EDEDED;
} 
#nav a:hover 
{
 color:#BDBDBD;
}

#body 
{
 width:850px;
 margin:0px auto;
 margin-top:80px;
 font-family:verdana;
}

body 
{
 margin:0px;
}
```

I've tried many times to change the position, but failed. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so, make sure to mark the one that did as the accepted answer. If it's my or Ampersand's answer, mark his as he was first.

Answer (score 9):

Under #nav in your CSS just change:

```
top:0px;
```

to

```
bottom:0px;
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 6):

In your CSS for `#nav` change

```
top:0px;
```

To

```
bottom:0px;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your css file, under nav just switch the top:0px to bottom:0px , like this

```
#nav
 {
 background-color:#262626;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 50px #5E5E5E;
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it fixed to the bottom of the page? Or just the bottom of the div?

Try changing "top:0px;" to "bottom:0px;".

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav 
{
    clear: both;
}
```

try this, but your making thing harder when your using positioning and floating at the same time.